# Why can't we use "almost" and "quite" together? (My textbook says we can't)

Tags: adverbs, syntax

I came to know that "almost" and "quite" are not used together. But I don't get the reason why these two words can't be together.

In my textbook, it's written that *quite* and *almost* both are adverbs and we don't use any other adverb before *quite*, but adverbs can also be used to qualify another adverbs.

Please explain. For example, in this sentence:

> The AI players are almost quite competent in staying together as a team.

Comment: Because this is a forum dedicated to learning English, please refrain from using shorthand forms like "Plz" and "Thx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of **almost** as meaning roughly 90%. You could replace it with 90% in these examples:

> The performance was almost perfect
>   The cat was almost dead when we found it
>   He answered almost truthfully

Note that these adjectives and adverbs are all [non-gradable](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-gradability.htm). It is possible to use **almost** with gradable adjectives, but it is unusual.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/quite), **quite** has two meanings. If you use it with a non-gradable adjective or adverb, it means 100%, and if you use it with a gradable adjective or adverb, it means roughly 60%. You could replace it with 60% in these examples:

> The performance was quite good
>   The cat was quite hungry when we got home
>   He answered quite sensibly

**competent** is a gradable adjective (you can say that somebody is very competent), so **quite** in this context means 60%.

If you say **almost quite competent**, it's like saying **90% 60% competent**... it's not a sensible way of describing something. In addition, since 90% of 60% is 55%, you could just use **quite** on its own to mean 55%, as the percentages I have suggested are only approximate.

If you use **almost quite** with a non-gradable adjective like **dead**, it's like saying **90% 100% dead**: again, it's not a sensible way of describing something.

Comment: Does it mean that almost and quite can never be together ?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about a tall short person, but people do it: they exercise poetic licence. In the same way, it doesn't really make sense to put **almost quite** together, because they mean different things, but **never** is too strong a word to use, because people can use poetic licence to use words in ways that were never intended.